# How to connect a full web site rather than mobile programmatically from android applicaiton

Tags: android, html

How can I connect to a full web site rather than mobile web page from code? The reason why I ask this is when I try to connect a web site which has a mobile web site, it directs to mobile page so I can't get the content of the full site.

I'm using this code to connect to site but I tried two or three different code to connect all of them didn't work.

```
URL url = new URL(adress);

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); 

urlConnection.connect();

InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set proper header properties e.g. like this:

```
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset",
                "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        conn.setRequestProperty(
                "User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-gb,en;q=0.5");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://youtube.com");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "deflate");
```

Comment: Now, I have another problem, the site I'm trying to connect has different websites for different countries and it directs me to the website for my country but I want to connect only to the english one. What should I add more to requestProperty?

Comment: well..maybe you can add some post/get paramter in your requests. I.e. for market.android.com?hl=en you add hl desired language paramter. It´s hard to say, it can be also based on the location of your IP..